# iMacros Looping over predefined values of counter

Tags: javascript, loops, vbscript, nested-loops, imacros

I have links of webpages that differ only at `KFZID`. I have all of them.

URL GOTO=http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/detail.aspx?KFZID=240009

How can I make a LOOP in iMacros (I believe then with VBS or JavaScript) for all these predefined values of `KFZID` (webpages)?

Below it is a program that I´d like to run for each of those webpages (in total 60939 different KFZID)

```
'LOOP TO EXTRACT VARIABLE VALUES for each KFZID

VERSION BUILD=10012816
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP no
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

URL GOTO=http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/detail.aspx?KFZID=240009

set !var1 0
add !var1 {{!loop}}

TAG POS={{!var1}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:box-col2 EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ADACiMacro\1st_15x50 FILE=Extract_VALUES_240009.csv

'CLICK "PLAY LOOP" WITH MAX=166 AS THERE ARE 166 VARIABLE VALUES TO BE SELECTED
```

I appreciate any suggestions and comments.

Answer (score 1):

Put them in CSV file. Read csv file and place id inside ID part. This code has been tested. Worked on on my side.

```
VERSION BUILD=10012816
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS
'SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP no
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE C:\ids.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1


URL GOTO=http://www.adac.de/infotestrat/autodatenbank/detail.aspx?KFZID={{!COL1}}

set !var1 0
add !var1 {{!loop}}

TAG POS={{!var1}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:box-col2 EXTRACT=TXT

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ADACiMacro\1st_15x50 FILE=Extract_VALUES_240009.csv
```

Comment: Macroscripts, thanks for your reply. However, what I got with the proposed code is just one variable from each webpage (KFZID) in each excel sheet (I also specified to save SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=D:\ADACiMacro\1st_15x50 FILE=Extract_VALUES_{{!COL1}}.csv) as I have a LOOP over 166 variables (POS={{!var1}}) inside each webpage

Comment: So you want the script to loop 166 times on the link, then move over to a next link ? That can be done with JS scripting. Contact me via my website.

Comment: I would like to contact you via yur website but your contact form on the website does not allow it me)